# swiftmailer - setting path to attachment

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I don't know how to set path to attachment. I still get error :**Warning: fopen(/rs.pptx): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

I tried

```
->attach($at::fromPath('/rs.pptx')) 
->attach($at::fromPath('C:\xampp\htdocs\yt2\src\SklepBundle'))
```

etc.. but it does not work
When I send external resource, for example ->attach($at::fromPath('http://www...')) everything works fine.

How should I set it? Thanks for help in advance

Comment: What's the actual (full) path on your system please?

Comment: What do you mean "full path"? Do you mean "C:\xampp\htdocs\yt2\src\SklepBundle"?

Answer (score 0):

Try these, not sure which one will work:

```
->attach($at::fromPath('C:\xampp\htdocs\yt2\src\SklepBundle\rs.pptx'))
->attach($at::fromPath('../src/SklepBundle/rs.pptx'))
->attach($at::fromPath('C:/xampp/htdocs/yt2/src/SklepBundle/rs.pptx'))
```

I think one of those should work.